# How to p4 unshelve in a different client but keep the same shelve CL?

Tags: perforce

Hi I have two p4 clients, say client_a and client_b.

I made a shelf in client_a by:

```
$> p4 shelve ...
```

and I got a shelf CL 123456.

Then I want to unshelve the changes in client_b, but I want to keep the same CL# there.

The following command doesn't work:

```
$> p4 unshelve -s 123456 -c 123456
Change 123456 belongs to client client_a
```

How can I achieve that?

(FWIW, the reason I want to keep the CL# is because if I make further changes in client_b, I want to be able to archive the changes in the same CL# by

```
$> p4 shelve -r -c 123456
```

because multiple people are relying on the same CL# to get their work done. I don't want to create a new CL# and pass it around among many collaborators.)

Hope I made myself clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can keep the same changelist
but you can carry your shelve as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948905/how-to-unshelve-a-shelved-changelist-to-another-branch-prior-to-perforce-2013

Answer (score 2):

While it is technically possible to accomplish this by changing ownership of the shelf, it's the wrong tool for the job, like using the butt end of a screwdriver to pound a nail in.  You almost might as well give up using version control and just email the files to each other.

Submit this change to a branch that all of the collaborators can access.  This will allow everyone's work to be versioned.  Shelves are not versioned and are generally only suitable for workflows that involve a single author and little or no iteration (e.g. reviewing or backing up a one-off change).